# What is the comma (,) operator in assembly?

Tags: assembly, comma-operator

Here's a simple assembly language program i have written:

```
section .text
    global main     ;must be declared for linker (ld)
main:               ;tells linker entry point
    mov edx,len     ;message length
    mov ecx,msg     ;message to write
    mov ebx,1       ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov eax,4       ;system call number (sys_write)
    int 0x80        ;call kernel

    mov eax,1       ;system call number (sys_exit)
    int 0x80        ;call kernel

section .data
msg db 'Hello, world!', 0xa  ;our dear string
len equ $ - msg              ;length of our dear string
```

now i dont know what is happening in this line: `msg db 'Hello, world!', 0xa`
i know the meaning of `msg db 'Hello, world!'` but the problem rises when i see the comma and `0xa` after that..

After some research i cam to know that the `0xa` causes a line break but i just dont understand why is a comma used there?

Is it some sort of concatenation or something?
like the c(++) syntax: `cout << "asdfsdf" << var;`
or perhaps the Java syntax: `System.out.println("Hello,"+var+"!");` or python syntax: `print 'Yo '+var`

please help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That line is simply declaring a label named `msg` in the data segment.  `msg` is pointing to a byte buffer initialized with the characters `Hello, world!`, immediately followed by a newline character (0x0A).  The line after that is calculating the length of the string by taking the difference between the current address and the `msg` label.  The `len` symbol will hold that length.  The use of the comma is not an operator, it's simply just a separator between the values you are using to initialize the buffer.

Strings are treated specially in most (if not all) assembly languages to make it more convenient to write.  That way you don't have to write out every individual character in that string.

The following declarations are equivalent:

```
str1 db 'abcde'
str2 db 0x61, 'bc', 'd', 101
; 'a' is 0x61 hex
; 'e' is 101 decimal
```

Just be warned that they usually don't automatically include a null terminator.  This is why you would typically see a string declared like this:

```
message db 'Hello world', 0
```

Comment: okay... so when you concatenate a string and a number the number is converted into its ASCII string and then used is it?

Comment: You have it the other way around. A string in assembly is just a convenient way to initialize a set of byte values. Each character in the string is stored as a byte value (it's ASCII value) and stored sequentially in the order they are written. You shouldn't think of it as string concatenation in this context, that's not really what's happening here.

Comment: @tenstar: Think of this like alternate ways to write a C initializer for a char array.  Like `static char str1[] = "abcde";` (although that includes a `'\0'` byte).  Or `char str2 = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 0 };`   Assembly allows a mix between those syntaxes in the same `db` pseudo-instruction, which just takes a list of byte value and assembles them into the output file at the current position.  NASM does interpolate C-style escapes inside backticks, so you can do ```db `Hello\n` ```; that's exactly equivalent.

Comment: And BTW, when you're using an explicit length, like with a `write` system call in this case, you normally *don't* want to write a literal `0` byte as part of it, so shouldn't include one. Definitely not before the `len equ $ - msg` anyway.  The `,0` makes it a zero-terminated C-string you could pass to `puts` or whatever.

Answer (score 4):

The comma operator, when used with `db`, is a concatenation.

The reason that the newline (`0xa`) is concatenated to the end of the `'Hello, world!'` is because when displaying the string, it is a good idea to include a newline afterwards.

Without it, if you looped this code, you would get:

`Hello, world!Hello, world!Hello, world!Hello, world!Hello, world!Hello, world!`

But with a newline:

```
Hello, world!
Hello, world!
Hello, world!
Hello, world!
Hello, world!
Hello, world!
```

Comment: okay... so when you concatenate a string and a number the number is converted into its ASCII string and then used is it?